# Flink Kafka Consumer offset getting reset to 0 on job resart

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

The issue that I am encountering is that the FlinkKafkaConsumer offsets gets reset to 0 when Kafka and the Flink job are restarted and as a result the data gets reprocessed even though I have checkpointing enabled and I have exactly-once semantics enabled in the Flink job.

Here is my environment details

- Running under Kubernetes
- Kafka source topic has 10 partitions with no replication.
- Kafka has 3 brokers.
- Flink checkpointing is enabled with exactly once semantics.
- Flink version is 1.12
- Flink connects to Kafka via a load balancer

The issue only happens when there is more than 1 partition for the source topic and Flink is not able to connect to all the 3 brokers across which the partitions are distributed. The offsets get reset to 0 for only the partitions not available in the broker that Flink initially connects to.  If I wait to restart the Flink job after all the 3 brokers are available there is no issue.  Here are the KafkaConsumer settings

auto.offset.reset: earliest
isolation.level: read_committed

I also have setStartFromGroupOffsets and setCommitOffsetsOnCheckpoints enabled on KafkaConsumer.

Note that I ensured that all the data in the topic was consumed by the job and Flink had successfully checkpointed the data by verifying the committed offsets in Kafka. Any help resolving this issue is much appreciated.

I don't know if this is a Flink issue or a Kafka Client issue.  Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's realistic to expect any guarantees from a setup like this that doesn't have any replication set up.

Comment: So is the alternative to ensure that the replication for all topics be set to N where N is the number of brokers?  If there are 9 brokers would that mean the replication needs to be set to 9 to ensure the data from all partitions are always available?

Comment: There should be enough replication to ensure that all partitions are always available. Otherwise, there's no way to know the offsets for the unavailable partition(s).